# Upgrading Sharp Architecture from 1.9.6 to 2.0.x

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, sharp-architecture

I have an existing ASP.NET MVC3 site that has been built with Sharp Architecture 1.9.6 and I'd like to upgrade to 2.0.4.

I've used NuGet to: `Update-Package sharp-architecture`. Obviously there are a number of compile issues...so I've been trying to update the references using the [version history](https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Sharp-Architecture/blob/master/VersionHistory.txt) as a rough guide.

Unfortunately, it hasn't helped all that much since namespaces like SharpArch.Infrastructure seem to have disappeared somewhere between 2.0.0 --> 2.0.4 which is odd because I thought they used Semantic Versioning... but anyway...

I've been searching the interwebs for a guide on how to upgrade and I haven't come across anything helpful. Even reading through the [sharp architecture blog](http://blog.sharparchitecture.net/) hasn't helped me with this problem...

So does anyone know if there is a guide for how to upgrade to version 2.0.x? Surely it must be possible. Or is one expected to start a new site using Templify?